# Transferring domains to save money

Tags: domain-registration, domain-registrar

I have about 35 domains and I was wondering, does it hurt in anyway to keep transferring between name cheap and godaddy year after year to save some cash? I haven't actually done it but is it frowned upon, especially with google search algorithms?

Comment: Your domains would be seen as unstable. Google checks the domain registration, host, IP address, etc. and looks for unusual activity. Do not give them a reason to think you are a jerk. Please.

Comment: Are these all active websites - 35 domains?? I am really not sure if it will hurt seo as long as there is no downtime during the switch. However, I feel this is worthless exercise if you have 35 active websites - you already have enough on your plate.

Comment: Aside: Coupled with the time/hassle of actually doing this I'd be very surprised if you really saved anything by "keep" changing registrars. In my experience, registrars are either consistently higher or lower for certain TLDs - their prices don't fluctuate so much. So, if you are wanting to save your pennies then transfer to the lower priced registrar (in the first year) and relax. The monetary savings the registrars offer are usually only for _new_ registrations, not domain transfers/renewals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The cash you save will not be worth your time managing the transfers.**

Nothing else need really come into it. Domains are so cheap nowadays, you may as well have a favourite registrar and keep all your domains together to make it easy to manage. And then spend the time you would have spent on transferring them... on something that will make you some money instead! (such as working on things that will optimise your SEO, working on increasing ad income, etc)

If you did want to transfer back and forth anyway, it's unlikely it will affect your SEO. Where a domain is registered doesn't have  any bearing on the content of the site, which is much more important. However, since it's hard to know *for sure* and there's very little benefit in transferring back and forth, I'd recommend not doing it.

Comment: I don't quite agree. I don't know the internal but several sites do claim that registration stability ranks a domain higher in SERPs. I agree with @closenotc's comment above

Comment: @AJ. Can you provide a reference to one of these "several sites"? Also, the OP is only proposing to change the domain registrar at most _once a year_.

Comment: @w3dk One of them is https://searchenginewatch.com/sew/news/2064522/website-changes-that-will-hurt-your-seo. I've seen similar such claims on other forums and websites. As I mentioned in my original comments, I don't know the internals of the algorithms used by Google

Comment: @AJ. Although the article on searchenginewatch.com is regarding a change in owner/registrant (not simply the registrar).

Answer (score 1):

Do you have you have private whois records? If the records are not private and you just change your domain registrar I don't think there will be any consequences but it is really hard to say as I haven't actually tested it on a larger scale and repeated the process. I have just moved domain from one registrar to another and never noticed any issues.